# Did this downvote come when the upvotes hit 667?

Tags: discussion, voting

So I just noticed the votes expandable shows that Jon Skeet's got a downvote- My curiosity is burning. Is there any way to tell if this is just a troll making it go to 666?

[image]

Question link is here: [Interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded)

Comment: Because only the devil himself dares to downvote Jon Skeet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer in: no.

As can be seen in the [answer's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2483688/timeline), the downvote was cast back in Sep 26 2012:

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

No, the downvote was long before the answer hit 666 upvotes.